# How do I to export utf8mb4 mysql data using php to a csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv, utf-8, utf8mb4

I am looking for help on a csv file export.

I have a mysql database encoded as utf8mb4 (unicode_ci) with a table using collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci for my fields.  The data contains special characters such as copyright symbols, foreign characters such as "é", etc.  I am trying to export data to a csv file but the string values that contain special characters are not translating over properly.  For example, the copyright symbol comes up as "¬Æ" in the csv file I generate.

My environment is Laravel 7, PHP 7 and MySQL 5.7 on Ubunutu 18.0.4.  My database connection is already setup as charset = "utf8mb4" and collation = "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" in my Laravel database config file.  The meta tag in my page header is already set to use charset=utf-8 and the header used to generate the csv file is set to:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
```

I have tried using:

```
iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $mystring);
```

but this only replaces some of the values with ascii representations and not the proper symbols.  I have also tried using something like

```
htmlspecialchars($mystring, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

but this still returns "¬Æ" for the copyright symbol and other strange character sequences in the csv file.  When I echo the values in php, they appear correctly on my page.   Am I right in thinking that I need to somehow convert the utf8mb4 string to regular utf-8 when I append the row to my csv file?  I have not been able to find a solution and am looking for some help.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get the expected symbols in my csv file?

Comment: You don't show the code you use to actually write the file. Also, you don't say how you're inspecting the result (if you are using Excel, that could be the problem).

Comment: It's not that the data is not exporting properly, it's that the program that is _reading or displaying_ it is not using the correct charset. You can try adding a UTF8 BOM `\xEF\xBB\xBF` to the beginning of the file and the program _may_ use that as a signal to apply the correct charset. Failing that, look up how to open UTF8 CSVs properly in that program. Failing _that_ you'll need to translate the data to a charset that the program _does_ handle correctly.

Comment: Weird… Do you mean  `©` (U+00A9,  *Copyright Sign*)
or `®` (U+00AE,  *Registered Sign*) by "*this still returns "¬Æ" for the copyright symbol*"? Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: What's the hexadecimal representation of `é`. Use a hex editor to find out. This will help finding out what encoding the source is.

Answer (score 0):

[Jerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491754/jerry)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72662428/how-do-i-to-export-utf8mb4-mysql-data-using-php-to-a-csv-file/72687788#comment128352515_72662428)

> You don't show the code you use to actually write the file. Also, you don't say how you're inspecting the result (if you are using Excel, that could be the problem).

and [Sammitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064767/sammitch)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72662428/how-do-i-to-export-utf8mb4-mysql-data-using-php-to-a-csv-file/72687788#comment128353087_72662428)

> It's not that the data is not exporting properly, it's that the program that is reading or displaying it is not using the correct charset. You can try adding a UTF8 BOM `\xEF\xBB\xBF` to the beginning of the file and the program may use that as a signal to apply the correct charset. Failing that, look up how to open UTF8 CSVs properly in that program. Failing that you'll need to translate the data to a charset that the program does handle correctly.

were helpful. I was using Excel to preview the file. When I looked at the raw csv data in a code editor, the expected characters are there so it is something with the way Excel handles the file. Since I am working on a Mac and the © symbol is being entered with [Option] + [G], the é is [Option] + [E], etc. it would make sense that it could be a translation problem with how Excel reads the file. Adding `\xEF\xBB\xBF` to the beginning of the file seems to have done the trick!

Comment: \xEF\xBB\xBF is the "BOM" which indicates that the encoding for the file is UTF-8.  (Only a few products use it.)

Answer (score 0):

- If you stored utf8 values into a column declared latin1, fix that first.
- Do not use any conversion routines.
- Do verify the data in the tables using `SELECT(hex)` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

More:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)